# Optimizing hive queries

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to optimize hive query. I have partitioned and stored my base table as ORC file as shown below.

```
create table if not exists processed (
    plc string,
    direction string,
    table int,
    speed float,
    time string
) PARTITIONED BY (time_id bigint) STORED AS ORC;
```

I am firing the below query on the above table (contains 500.000 records). The final result I get is stored as a `json`. The whole transaction takes about 35 secs. Is there a way wherein I can reduce this time. Or may be, someone could suggest me using a different framework instead of Hive. This is the query :

```
String finalQuery = "select plc,direction,AVG(speed) as speed ,COUNT(plc) as count,time_id from processed WHERE plc IN "
                + " "
                + "("
                + plcCSV
                + ")"
                + " " + " " + "AND" + " " + "time_id =" + " " + time_id + " " 
                + "group by plc,direction,time_id";
```

Comment: let me share simply count of rows based on where condition.

Comment: @ZafarMalik ..The In clause in the where condition contains a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create an index on plc column and then try.

Comment: I have tried that too ..CREATE INDEX one ON TABLE processed(plc) AS 'COMPACT' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;

Comment: what exact data type and its length for plc like int, varchar, text etc.

Comment: I have taken plc as string

Comment: are you using mssql or mysql. is plc field indexed or you got any issue during index creation...if this columns size is long (i am not aware about string data type) but this columns contains only 5 or 6 digits values then create index only on required digits.....if you are not getting performance by this then first you can filter data in a sub-query then do group by and count on this sub-query data. In this way you can get performance but it will depend on filtered data suppose your table have 5 lacs rows and after filtering you are getting 50,000 rows then you can get performance.

Comment: I am using Hive. I indexed the table based on plc (contains 5 digits), but it didnt help me. Should I think of some other framework instead of Hive?

Comment: I don't have any idea of Hive, please share some sample data so that I can help you if mysql query will give performance or not.